# Converting exponent to binary and evaluating the modular exponential?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, modular-arithmetic

I am learning how to convert exponent to binary and evaluating the modular exponential. I believe I've done one problem right, using this method:

3 ^25 mod 7

3 ∧ 25 = 847,288,609,443$

25-16 = 9, 9-8 = 1, → (3^16) * (3^8) * (3^1) = 847,288,609,443  so…

3^1 mod 7 = (3 mod 7) = 3

3^8 mod 7 = (3^4 mod 7)² mod 7  = 81²  mod 7 = 16 mod 7 = 2

3^16 mod 7 = (3^8 mod 7)² mod 7 = 6561² mod 7 = 4

then we have:

3^25 mod 7 =  ((3 * 2 mod 7) * 2 mod 7) * 4 mod 7) = 6

However, my next problem is 7^644 mod 645, and I'm not sure where to begin because I can't even calculate 7^644 to get the initial number, like I did on my first problem. If you could offer some tips or a trick similar to the method above, I'd appreciate! Once I can figure out where to start I can do the rest.

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't really need to calculate $3^{25}$ for the first problem.  Where did you use that $847 \dots$ number?

Comment: I used it to find out which exponents I needed to multiply by, the line 25 - 16, and 9-8 = 1 give me the exponents 3^16, 3^8, and 3^1 which are equivelant to 847,288,609,443, and by break them down each by mod 7, I got the numbers for the last part of the equation

Comment: But you only used the number $25$ to find the exponents.  Likewise you can write $644$ in binary to find the exponents for the new problem.  You don't need to calculate $7^{644}$.

Comment: I suppose I just used 847,288,609,443 to check and confirm the exponents I was using were correct

Comment: Since the binary number of 644 is 1010000100, would the exponents be 4, 128, and 255? ie, 3^255+3^128+3^4?